# SaltStack: Getting Up and Running Minion on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, salt-stack

I am working through [the SaltStack walk through](http://docs.saltstack.com/topics/tutorials/walkthrough.html) to set up salt on my ec2 cluster.  I just edited `/etc/salt/minion` and added the public dns of my salt master.

```
master: ec2-54-201-153-192.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Then I restarted the minion.  In debug mode, this put out the following

```
$ sudo salt-minion -l debug
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[INFO    ] Using cached minion ID: localhost.localdomain
[DEBUG   ] loading log_handlers in ['/var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/log_handlers', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/log/handlers']
[DEBUG   ] Skipping /var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/log_handlers, it is not a directory
[DEBUG   ] None of the required configuration sections, 'logstash_udp_handler' and 'logstash_zmq_handler', were found the in the configuration. Not loading the Logstash logging handlers module.
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/minion
[INFO    ] Setting up the Salt Minion "localhost.localdomain"
[DEBUG   ] Created pidfile: /var/run/salt-minion.pid
[DEBUG   ] Chowned pidfile: /var/run/salt-minion.pid to user: root
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/minion
[DEBUG   ] loading grain in ['/var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/grains', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/grains']
[DEBUG   ] Skipping /var/cache/salt/minion/extmods/grains, it is not a directory
[DEBUG   ] Attempting to authenticate with the Salt Master at 172.31.21.27
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem
```

Sure enough, `172.31.21.27` is the private ip of the master.  So far this looks ok.  According to the walkthrough, the next step is to accept the minions key on the master:

```
"Now that the minion is started it will generate cryptographic keys and attempt to 
connect to the master. The next step is to venture back to the master server and 
accept the new minion's public key."
```

However, when I go to the master node and look for new keys I don't see any pending requests.

```
$ sudo salt-key -L
Accepted Keys:
Unaccepted Keys:
Rejected Keys:
```

And the ping test does not see the minion either:

```
$ sudo salt '*' test.ping
```

This is where Im stuck, what should I do next to get up and running?

Comment: *"The Salt Master needs to bind to 2 TCP network ports on the system, these ports are 4505 and 4506"* (from the walk-through)... are you allowing access to these in the security group?  If all machines are in the same security group, you should be able to specify the security group (sg-xxxxxxxx) as the "source" address instead of an IP address.  Also, you need to not have iptables or anything else blocking connections.

Comment: Ah, of course, I forgot to flush ip tables when I spun up my ops box.  Thanks very much, I just accepted the key for the first minion and the ping test passes.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off iptables and do `salt-key -L` to check if the key shows up. If it does, then you need to open port 4505 and 4506 on the master for the minion to be able to connect to it. You could do `lokkit -p tcp:4505 -p tcp:4506` to open these ports.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add rules for `4505/4506` between the salt master and minion `security group`.  Salt master needs these ports to be able to communicate with the minions.